# delete rows based on a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below dataframe

```
In [62]: df
Out[62]:
            coverage   name  reports  year
Cochice           45  Jason        4  2012
Pima             214  Molly       24  2012
Santa Cruz       212   Tina       31  2013
Maricopa          72   Jake        2  2014
Yuma              85    Amy        3  2014
```

Basically i can filter the rows as below

```
df[df["coverage"] > 30
```

and i can drop/delete a single row as below

```
df.drop(['Cochice', 'Pima'])
```

But i want to delete a certain number of rows based on a condition, how can i do so?

Comment: Can you explain more your condition?

Comment: I want to delete rows if the value of coverage column in less than 72

Comment: Then use boolean indexing - `df[df["coverage"] >= 72]`

Comment: Yes i got that, just curious if i can get more ways and so posted here :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best is [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) but need invert condition - get all values equal and higher as `72`:

```
print (df[df["coverage"] >= 72])
            coverage   name  reports  year
Pima             214  Molly       24  2012
Santa Cruz       212   Tina       31  2013
Maricopa          72   Jake        2  2014
Yuma              85    Amy        3  2014
```

It is same as [`ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ge.html) function:

```
print (df[df["coverage"].ge(72)])
            coverage   name  reports  year
Pima             214  Molly       24  2012
Santa Cruz       212   Tina       31  2013
Maricopa          72   Jake        2  2014
Yuma              85    Amy        3  2014
```

Another possible solution is invert mask by `~`:

```
print (df["coverage"] < 72)
Cochice        True
Pima          False
Santa Cruz    False
Maricopa      False
Yuma          False
Name: coverage, dtype: bool

print (~(df["coverage"] < 72))
Cochice       False
Pima           True
Santa Cruz     True
Maricopa       True
Yuma           True
Name: coverage, dtype: bool


print (df[~(df["coverage"] < 72)])
            coverage   name  reports  year
Pima             214  Molly       24  2012
Santa Cruz       212   Tina       31  2013
Maricopa          72   Jake        2  2014
Yuma              85    Amy        3  2014
```

Answer (score 2):

we can use pandas.query() functionality as well

```
import pandas as pd 

dict_ = {'coverage':[45,214,212,72,85], 'name': ['jason','Molly','Tina','Jake','Amy']}
df  = pd.DataFrame(dict_)

print(df.query('coverage > 72'))
```

[image]