# Delete pandas df rows on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas

Given the following two pandas Dataframes `df1` & `df2` I am trying to delete all rows from `df1["a"]` (strings) which do not match with any of the strings from all the entries of `df2["z"]`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['use social tag', 'dubmod intern workshop data', 
                           'deep collabor filter', 'pathrank a novel node rank'],
                    'b' : ["test", "test2" ,"test3", "test4"]})

df1

    a                            b
0   use social tag               test
1   dubmod intern workshop data  test2
2   deep collabor filter         test3
3   pathrank a novel node rank   test4



df2 = pd.DataFrame({'z' : ['experiment', 'dubmod intern workshop data', 
                           'deep collabor filter', 'experiment3']})

df2

    z
0   experiment
1   dubmod intern workshop data
2   deep collabor filter
3   experiment3
```

The result should look like this:

```
    a                            b
0   dubmod intern workshop data  test2
1   deep collabor filter         test3
```

Comment: Don't think regex is the tool for the job

Comment: `df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'z': 'a'}))`. It's an exact match right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete rows based on a condition in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833624/delete-rows-based-on-a-condition-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fully meet you requirements, I mean to "regenerate" also the index, run:

```
df1[df1.a.isin(df2.z)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for exact matches, it's really simple:

```
df1[df1['a'].isin(df2['z'])].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Instead of delete, you are filtering `df1` for rows that are in `df2`.

Comment: This works fine if you don't want to refresh the index.

Comment: @Peet all you have to do is to add `.reset_index(drop=True)`