# How can I drop rows in pandas based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to drop some rows in a pandas data frame, but I'm getting this error: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

I have a list of desired items that I want to stay in the Data Frame, so I wrote this:

#

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

biog = sys.argv[1]

df = pd.read_csv(biog, sep ='\t')

desired = ['Affinity Capture-Luminescence', 'Affinity Capture-MS', 'Affinity Capture-Western', 'Co-crystal Structure', 'Far Western', 'FRET', 'PCA', 'Reconstituted Complex']

new_df = df[['OFFICIAL_SYMBOL_A','OFFICIAL_SYMBOL_B','EXPERIMENTAL_SYSTEM']]


for i in desired:
    print(i)
    new_df.drop(new_df[new_df.EXPERIMENTAL_SYSTEM != i].index, inplace = True)
print(new_df)
```

#

it works if I place a single condition at a time, but when the for loop is inserted it doesn't work.

I didn't placed here the data because it is too large, I hope that this is enough.

thanks for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [delete rows based on a condition in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833624/delete-rows-based-on-a-condition-in-pandas)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a new df of when a column is in a list of values. No need to loop it.

```
new_df = new_df[new_df['EXPERIMENTAL_SYSTEM'].isin(desired)]
```

Comment: @LucasLazari, no problem! Could you mark it as the correct answer? It's the checkmark just bellow the upvote/downvote arrows.